# To modify start-up behavior of an MFC app

Tags: mfc, command-line-arguments

This is my first substantial MFC application.

My out-of-the-wizard MFC app wants to open a blank, new file of the type I specified for my app, when it starts, but that's not meaningful for my application.  I want my app to open some connections to some remote sites and get data from them.

Where should I consider interrupting or overriding MFC's default behavior?  I could subclass CWinApp::ProcessShellCommand().  I could modify the CCommandLineInfo object it works on.  I could excise the whole command line processing and just call my go-get-the-data functions.  I probably should just altogether excise the whole document-as-a-file related processing.  I'm not opening or saving any files, except debug files or logs that are outside of the UI's concern.  The only saving or collecting of local information is via a database, to which and from which I handle the serialization myself, so no CArchive, either.

I've got all this code but it's hanging in front of me disjointed and disintegrated.  I'm too new to this and there's too many alternatives.  Some simple guidance for a simple beginner is what I'm asking for.

So, if you'll say, sure, lop off the document-as-file handling, tell me, please, where I need to go to do that bit of surgery, I can see it's not just one object that'd be  affected.  And so forth.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider generating a new application, but when you do, tell it that you want a database application without file handling. Even if you don't use its database capability, it'll produce an application whose basic layout is set up roughly for what you're trying to do, so you'll basically just substitute your database interface for what it provides, but won't get involved with trying to rip out file handling and such that's apparently irrelevant for your program.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I need more of the UI functionality than the database project provides.  Which will serve better, building what I need myself or ripping out what interferes and what I don't need?  I don't know.  Either way, I'll advance in learning how to handle MFC, which is my goal.

Comment: @Shellsunder: what UI functionality is missing? AFAIK, it includes all the same UI functionality as any other project...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer with respect to modifying default file opening.  While I made the database app Coffin suggested, I saw the phrase "storing database objects in views" and I rather aimlessly searched MSDN with that.  If I was going to try the database app approach and do my own serialization, I had to learn about this.

I thus found an MSDN page concerning [handling the file menu in database apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfs33h24%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), which discusses how to alter and even disable the OnFileOpen command.  It's applicable to OnFile New and it is the approach I was hoping for.